# Implementing Gradcam on Siamese network?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, data-visualization

I am a beginner in deep learning and I am experimenting on siamese networks. I learnt that we can visualize any CNN network using grad cam. I want to visualize how the network is working using grad cam but I could not find any implementations related to that on the web and couldn't code it on my own too for siamese network. Can anyone help me out?

This is the network I created but don't know how to use grad cam to visualize it.

Thank you

```
class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.cnn1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            nn.Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=3),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(4),

            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            nn.Conv2d(4, 8, kernel_size=3),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8),


            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 8, kernel_size=3),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8),


        )

        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(8*200*200, 500),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Linear(500, 500),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Linear(500, 5))

    def forward_once(self, x):
        output = self.cnn1(x)
        output = output.view(output.size()[0], -1)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        return output

    def forward(self, input1, input2):
        output1 = self.forward_once(input1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(input2)
        return output1, output2
```

Comment: Did you come with a solution?